# Set State not getting called in parent function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a function defined in my component class which is calling it's parent function where that child is being utilized.

```
completeSession(id) {
  this.props.completeSession(id);
}
```

This function calls the parent function with id. The parent function is:

```
completeSession(id) {
  console.log("Entered parent complete Session");
  console.log(id);
  this.setState({feedback_id: id});
  console.log(this.state.feedback_id);
}
```

Here as you can see I have 3 `console logs` and my `console.log(id)` is giving a proper value but `this.state.feedback_id` comes as undefined. Over here the `this.setState` should update feedback_id and this should update the child component also.

```
renderPast() {

  return(
    <PastSessions timezone={this.state.timezone}
                  feedback_id={this.state.feedback_id}
                  sessions={this.state.sessions}
                  completeSession={this.completeSession.bind(this)}
                  cancelSession={this.cancelSession.bind(this)} />
  )
}
```

So I'm passing the `feedback id` back to the component so I'm not sure why it is not setting the state as intended. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep in mind that `setState` is asynchronous - so state is not updated immidiately after calling it. You can provide a callback function as `setState` second argument which will be called when the state is actually updated:

```
this.setState({feedback_id: id}, () => {
    console.log('state updated');
    console.log(this.state.feedback_id);
});
```

According to React [setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) documentation:

> ... the second parameter is an optional callback function that will be
>   executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.
>   Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic
>   instead.
>
> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.